# How to declare an array with one item calling a function?

Tags: php

I'm working on a project that will produce lots of tables from data stored in a text files.

anyway I want to have my code look something like this ..

```
   function Phone($arg){
   ....
   return $phone_nr
   }

   function Adress($arg){
   ....
   return $adress_nr
   }

   function Arr_push($args) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) {
            $keys[$i - 1] = func_get_arg($i);
        }
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $arr_return[] = $key;
        }
        return $arr_return;
    }

    $Table1[] = Arr_push($DB,'Name:', 'John', 'Gender:', 'male');
    $Table1[] = Arr_push($DB,'phone:', Phone('John'), 'Address', Adress('John'));

    $table = new TableClass();
    $table->show($Table1);

    ($DB is the database a 2d array with keys and values)
```

Could this be done ? Or do I have to write a some kind of parser for this

```
"Parser method"

 $Table1[] = Arr_push('phone:', '^phone,John', 'Address', ^adress,John');

 in Arr_push function check if the string start with a '^'. In that case explode
 it on the delimiter ',' and have switch loop for the different cases.
```

I have been searching for this several days no so I have to raise the question.

Extends the information ...

the file look like this ...

1 2 
PRD~1 3 
ISO 8859-1~1 4 0 ~2 1 
Rundvirke Skog~2 2 
VIRK1209.APT~3 1 
311214~3 2 
000000~3 3 1 ~803 4 
311214~3 5 
Valmet~3 6 
911.3~3 7 
........it goes on and on

Have managed with awful regex :

```
%((\d{1,}\s?)+(?=~))|(((\d{1,}\s\d{1,})\s?\r?\n)(^(\w|\s|[å-ö]|[Å-Ö]|,|\.|
    \?|-|\?|@|\*|/)+))%mx
```

read it into a 2d array like this  ...

```
[Var_id] [Type]  [Data]
 1        4       0 
 1        3       ISO 8859-1
 1        2       PRD
 2        2       VIRK1209.APT
 2        1       Rundvirke Skog
 3        6       911.3
 3        7       Valmet 
 3        8       360.1/360.2
 3        5       Valmet
 3        3       1
 3        2       000000
  .....
```

The output I want is table with some data for exampel

```
| Machine   | Valmet  | Type  | 911.3
| ......    | ......
```

The data (Valmet and 911.3) is called by its [Var_id] and  [Type]

So when doing thoose tables i would be nice to have a "clean" code

```
   $array[] = arr_push($DB, 'Produktion:', '', 'Apteringsinstruktion:', '');
    $array[] = arr_push($DB, 'FilNamn:', '^get, 1, 2', 'Filnamn:', '^get, 2, 2');
    $array[] = arr_push($DB, 'Nollställ datum:', '^get, 11, 4', 'Indetitetsuppgifter', '^get, 2, 1');
    $array[] = arr_push($DB, 'Lagrind datum:', '^get, 12, 4', 'Skapat datum:', '^get, 13, 4');
    display_table($array);

    How the input looks like now with the "parser" method.
```

So is there way to replace this '^get,var_id,type' parser with a function call instead?

More info about the StandforD standard could be found on : http://www.skogforsk.se/en/About-skogforsk/Collaboration-groups/StanForD/

More on the file wich explain [var_id] [type]  : http://www.skogforsk.se/PageFiles/60712/AllVarNo_ENG_120418.pdf.

Background:
Harvester is producing prd files wich include all the timber and volyme and time etc.. There are no free viewers for that on the market (what I know about). So I'm doing a prd viewer i PHP.

I don't know where to host this so I don't want a sql server as backend.

Comment: please show what data structure you want from this: `$Table1[] = Arr_push('Name:', 'John', 'Gender:', 'male');`

Comment: You do know that a) there is a native function called [`array_push()`](http://php.net/array-push) that does almost exactly what your `Arr_push()` function does and b) there is a function called [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func-get-args) that returns all the function arguments as an array? *Edit* and c) that whole thing could just be replaced with a standard array declaration

Comment: Show us example input and requested output.

Comment: Ok will try to explain more ..

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc($a)
{
    return '2'.$a;
}

$array = Array('a','^abc,a');
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $a = substr($value,0,1);
    if ($a=='^')
    {
        $e = explode(',',$value);
        $func = substr($e[0],1);
        unset($e[0]);
        // return any second, thrird... commas
        $value2 = implode(',',$e);
        $value3 = call_user_func_array($func,Array($value2));
        $array[$key] = $value3;
    }
}

echo var_dump($array);
```

result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string '2a' (length=2)
```

Comment: well if you want, (it will not go over well on the site, but it is fair in this context), you could always use "eval":

eval('$value = Phone("john")')

Answer (score 0):

That's the route I'm going for the moment. The negative part is that the "function call"

> '^abc,a'

will have the same color as the other strings in syntax highlightning (using netbeans).
Was testing with lambada but it seems that it will not work in array.

Why will this not work?

```
$hello = function() {
   return 'hello world';
};

$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry", hello());
print_r($stack);
```